# how to handle login-error in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and python. I have a website to which users can log in. I need to improve the security.

what i want to do is: when a user try many wrong passwords, I ban him further trying, ask him email and ask the user to reset password in the case the user forget the password.

I reviewed documentations about flask-admin, flask-secure. Since I am new to this, don't know where to start.

does flask-secure provide features to do what I want? or should I look into something also?

Comment: @KlausD. I tried to understand the program. now, don't know which library I need to use. where to start?

Comment: The concept of Stack Overflow is that you give the code you have, you ask a specific question and get help on that. It's not a site for starter guide, library requests and broad how-tos.

Comment: @KlausD. I edited the question. If it does not meet the requirement, i will delete the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I approve of this feature. But it could be achieved by either a field in the user table of your database or a runtime dictionary. Choose whichever gives you the level of persistence you want.

When a user attempts to log in and fails you simply increment this field. And if the field reaches a certain value you lock the user or do whatever you want.

Sending an email in python can be found at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html).

As for a password reset system. 
When a user needs to reset their password you generate a key. This can be a base64-encoded string of random bytes. This key can be stored in the user table with en expiry datetime.

Now you can create a route in flask that takes this key as path- or query-parameter.
So when a user needs to reset their password you can send them a unique link with this key as a path- or query-param (whichever you choose).

Comment: After searching a while,I realized that flask-security does not provide features for what i want to do. Your idea seems the best. Thanks!